# Is George Pell the 3rd ranking official at the Vatican?

Tags: politics, vatican

News outlets have been referring to Cardinal George Pell as the 3rd highest ranked official of the Vatican. I wasn't aware that the Vatican had such hierarchical "rankings".  Here's a quote from [CNN](http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/28/asia/cardinal-pell-australia/index.html).

> Cardinal George Pell, a senior adviser to Pope Francis and the
>   third-ranking official in the Holy See, is taking leave from the
>   Vatican to fight historical sexual assault charges in his home country
>   of Australia.

In what sense is Cardinal George Pell the 3rd-ranking official in the Holy See?

Comment: Better on https://christianity.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Agree with fredsbend. If you want to know details of Cardinal Pell's position, best to ask where you are likely to find an expert on Vatican heirarchy.

Comment: I feel that Skeptics.SE may be a good match for this question, because it's dealing with suspected misinformation, as opposed to seeking expert knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traditionally, the [Cardinal Secretary of State](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_Secretary_of_State) represented the number two authority in the Vatican. This official and his department, the [Secretariat of State](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretariat_of_State_(Holy_See)), had wide authority over both foreign affairs and financial matters.

However, in 2014, this role was re-organized, with the Secretary of State keeping the foreign affairs responsibilities (much like the US's Secretary of State) while the financial roles were consolidated into the new [Secretariat  for the Economy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretariat_for_the_Economy), with George Pell as its first prefect.

In this sense, since the Cardinal Secretary of State was the old number two, the Prefect of the Secretariat for the Economy could be considered the number 3 job.

However, there are other job titles that could be considered of at least equal importance with those mentioned. Other contenders could be the [President of the Pontifical Commission for Vatican City State](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/President_of_the_Pontifical_Commission_for_Vatican_City_State), which is the president of the legislature; the [Camerlengo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camerlengo_of_the_Holy_Roman_Church), who administers the Vatican City and acts as acting Head of State during a Papal interregnum, or the [Dean of the College of Cardinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dean_of_the_College_of_Cardinals), who is the second most senior member of the Catholic Church.

Comment: @GEdgar Pell wasn't fired from his position?

Comment: @curiousdannii Pell has stood down to fight the criminal charges.  I can't find at the moment whether he has resigned permanently, or just taken a leave of absence.